# How find count of rows between two timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one table, called **df_1**

```
   start_time  end_time
0           0        30
1          77       107
2         220       250
3         268       298
4         391       421
```

I would like to know how many rows there are in another dataframe **df_2** between each *start_time* and *end_time* of **df_1**. **df_2** looks like this

```
   time
0   100
1   392
2   399
```

So, the result would look like this

```
   start_time  end_time  count
0           0        30      0
1          77       107      1
2         220       250      0
3         268       298      0
4         391       421      2
```

Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: how big are both dataframes?

Comment: It depends. df_1 is as such 50 rows only, and df_2 ~10 rows only. But - actually they both are part of a larger table with different game_ids, each having this 50 or 10 rows. And different game_ids there are thousands.

Comment: so your plan is to do the operation per games_id?

Comment: That would be optimal - and most optimally doing it in a fully vectorised way.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of useful built-in functions for doing what you are going to do. Here I used `between` (its document is available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)). The implementation would be like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start':[0, 77, 391],
             'End':[30, 107, 421]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':[100, 392, 399]})

df1['Count'] = df1.apply(lambda row:df2.time.between(row['Start'], row['End']).astype(int).sum(), axis=1)
df1
```

output:

```
   Start  End  Count
0      0   30      0
1     77  107      1
2    391  421      2
```

Comment: is there a reason that in the lambda func there is `df2.time` instead of `df2['time']` ?  Isn't the syntax with the brackets the more pythonic way to write it?

Comment: In fact, I don't have any preferences in this case. But here I preferred to stick with the `method chaining` style!

Comment: @Rabinzel my 2 cents on this question is: it is safer to use the bracket as a general rule, because the day you have a column that has a name similar to a method, like `df = pd.DataFrame({'min':[1,2]})`), then doing `df.min` won't select the column but it is understood as the method `min` associated to the dataframe df. Moreover it is a bit more flexible if you want to create a variable `col = 'min'`, then `df[col]` will work while `df.col` won't. anyway, I agree with meti that, in this case, it does not matter :)

Answer (score 1):

On top of my head, i think

```
df_1["count"] = df_1.apply(lambda x: df_2.time.between(x[0],x[1]).sum(),axis=1)
```

Should work, not sure about the time complexity.

Output

```
   start_time  end_time  count
0           0        30      0
1          77       107      1
2         220       250      0
3         268       298      0
4         391       421      2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options for this; the first involves IntervalIndex:

```py
from collections import Counter
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.start_time, df1.end_time, closed='both')

df1.index = intervals

filtered = intervals[intervals.get_indexer(df2.time)]

counts = Counter(filtered)

df1.loc[counts.keys(), 'count'] = [*counts.values()]

df1.fillna(0, downcast='infer').reset_index(drop=True)


   start_time  end_time  count
0           0        30      0
1          77       107      1
2         220       250      0
3         268       298      0
4         391       421      2
```

The other option involves [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which can help to abstract inequality joins:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df1.conditional_join(
         df2, 
        ('start_time', 'time', '<='), 
        ('end_time', 'time', '>='), 
        how = 'left')
    .groupby(['start_time', 'end_time'], as_index = False)
    .agg(count=('time', 'count'))
)

   start_time  end_time  count
0           0        30      0
1          77       107      1
2         220       250      0
3         268       298      0
4         391       421      2
```

The IntervalIndex option should be faster though, as the end goal is an aggregation (the intervalIndex option skips creating a dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way that doesn't use any implicit loop.

More verbose, but much faster (20% faster than lambda solutions)

```
# Turn df_2 into multiple-row df where row count equals df_1
df_2 = df_2[['time']].T
df_3 = df_2.loc[df_2.index.repeat(len(df_1))].copy()
df_3.index = df_1.index  # Aligns indices

events_after_start = df_3.T > df_1['start_time']
events_before_end = df_3.T < df_1['end_time']
df_1['Count'] = (events_after_start & events_before_end).T.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Nice! It would be awesome if you compiled speed tests for the answers so far, with varying data sizes if possible; it would be helpful for me and others as well

Comment: Actually, using %timeit the difference is not that big. 

meti's answer: 1.37 ms ± 4.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

MattiH's answer: 1.13 ms ± 4.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: True. Maybe try it on a significantly larger mock dataset. And if you can, do it for all the answers shared